# How to Control Visibility of items in a Linear Layout in my App?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have a Vertical linear layout with 2 item. One is a is a customview which is extended from a framelayout and the 2nd one is a textview with a drawable as background. The visibility have to be controlled dynamically **from gone to visible.**

The issue is that when i change the visibility of the item from gone to visible the order is not coming as i intended. The the second item is below the customview. I want it to come as the 2nd item, below the customview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:textureview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_holder"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.custom_views.CircularFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/comment_holder_circular_layout"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/comment_avatar_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/comment_avatar_width" />
            <com.custom_views.PlaybackTextureView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/playback_texture_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                textureview:isAuthorMode="true"/>
        </com.custom_views.CircularFrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/c_holder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble_top_arrow_orange"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_comment_user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black_50"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**NOTE**: I tried adding weight to the custom layout as 1. But it still didnt help.

Comment: first try and run your layout without hiding any view and see if its coming proper , than follow your steps it will work , this view is becoming visible at the same place it is , so you need to place it properly where you want and then it will work

Comment: @Thunder its not coming properly even if it is not hidden

Comment: Yes that's what the problem is

Comment: If possible can you share the snapshot and mention where you want the view position so I can make the required change in your code for you.

Comment: @Thunder i want the c_holder to be under comment_holder_circular_layout

Comment: okay give me few mins and try the answer

Comment: so you want to make all these view  visible is it